# SQL Server 2014 server name is blank

Tags: sql-server, server-name

I installed the SQL Server 2014 (express) on my laptop, but I couldn't connect to the database as the 'server name' is 'blank' & when I clicked on browse for more, I don't see any options there. Can anyone assist me with this?

[image]

Comment: Use the word `localhost` or period: `.` or the name of your PC or the ip address of your pc

Comment: It throws me a network related or instance specific error. Here's the error message

Comment: It provides this error " a network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: Named  Pipes Provided, error : 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL server)(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Open window's SERVICES  ... scroll down until you see SQL Server  ... right click and select START ...   You will exit out and reload SSMS.

Comment: Try `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: I do not see MS SQL server 2014 in the Services(Local)

Comment: Are you sure you installed SQL Server and not just the client tools (SSMS)?